# How to subscribe an SNS topic of one account by SQS of another account using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm trying to create an SNS topic in one account and attach it to Config Rules.
I have 3 such accounts and want to create SNS topic in each of the account.
Now i want to subscribe all of the 3 topics of 3 different accounts by SQS of the fourth account.

I'm able to do it manually. Can somebody please tell me how it can be done via boto3.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far with http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.subscribe

Comment: What steps did you take when you did it manually?

Comment: I have refered to the aws document [SendMessageToSQS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.cross.account.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to subscribe a SNS topic present in Account A by an SQS present in Account B using boto3, following is the procedure.

In Account A, create SNS topic and add the proper permission.
For example,

```
import boto3
sns_client = boto3.clien('sns')
topics = sns_client.create_topic(Name='SNS topic name')
sns_client.add_permission(
                TopicArn=str(topics['TopicArn']),
                Label=label,
                AWSAccountId=[
                    "AccountB_Id",
                ],
                ActionName=[
                    "GetTopicAttributes",
                    "SetTopicAttributes",
                    "AddPermission",
                    "RemovePermission",
                    "DeleteTopic",
                    "Subscribe",
                    "ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                    "Publish",
                    "Receive"
                ]
            )
```

Now to subscribe the created topic from Account B, execute the following code from account B.

```
import boto3
subscription_client = boto3.client('sns')
subscription_client.subscribe(
                TopicArn="ARN of the topic created",
                Protocol="sqs",
                Endpoint="ARN of the SQS present in Account B"
            )
```

Now you would see the SNS topic of account A been subscribed by account B.