# How to subscribe an SNS topic of one account by SQS of another account with filters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

My requirement is similar to what is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681508/how-to-subscribe-an-sns-topic-of-one-account-by-sqs-of-another-account-using-bot). But I want to add subscription filters and only subscribe to messages that match the filter criteria.

SQS is in Account A which is my account. SNS Topic is in Account B which is an account over which I have no control. However Account A is already provided root account access to access this topic in Account B.

How can I add filter conditions and consume only specific messages in SQS from SNS Topic?

Comment: What do you mean by "Account A is already provided root account access to access this topic in Account B"?

Comment: The SNS topic in Account B allows Account A to create topic subscription

Comment: Okay. So can you "create topic subscription" with a `FilterPolicy`? See: [Amazon SNS Subscription Filter Policies - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. I created a SNS subscription in Account A and chose the target as SQS queue in Account A. In SQS queue , when I add permissions with Principal = * and Actions = * , I am able to see messages flowing into SQS queue. However when I set Principal = account number of Account A , I don't see messages flowing into SQS queue. I don't want provided principal as * but want to lock down to specific accounts. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: I set the permissions similar to what is listed here and it fixed the issue - https://theburningmonk.com/2019/01/subscribe-sqs-to-a-sns-topic-in-another-aws-account-with-cloudformation-and-gotchas/. As specific here , I had to provide the ARN of topic in the source ARN field with principal = *. Why doesn't just setting root account of account B in principal work?

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question with a copy of the policy you used. We'll then be in a better position to comment on the question you just asked in the comment.